# Counter in Excel If else statement

Tags: vba, excel

I am stuck with an excel question and need help in creating a counter and add the micro seconds in Air Time field when Count Air Time is more than 1 to differentiate the unique records.

Incremental counter to the Air Time field to make it unique and remove duplicates:

[image: img1]

Thanks,
Nupur

Comment: You don't need to reference column K, use this in cell M7108 and copy up and down: `=IF(J7108=J7107,M7107+TIMEVALUE("0:00:00.01"),J7108)` and then make sure to format the cell as Custom with `h:mm:ss.00`

Comment: Do you really mean microseconds?  Milliseconds?

Comment: Its working, thanks for your help. Its milliseconds